# renaming problem of a element of a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python and trying to solve an issue I faced. It would be very kind if you could help me to sort it out. thanks in advance.
the issue is basically, I want to rename of an element of csv file. But I could not make it.

```
csv_data = open("sample2.csv")
names = []
numbers = []
for line in csv_data:
    a = line.split(',')
    names.append(a[0])
    
    b = (list(map(int, a[1:-1])))
    numbers.append(b)
i = 1
j = 0
while i < len(names)+1:
    print(i, '-', names[j])
    i+=1
    j+=1
choice = int(input('enter a choice:'))
new_name = input('please enter a new name: ')
selection = choice -1
names[selection] = new_name
```

from this moment on I do not know how to manipulate the csv file.
with this code: I tried to change score element as a score_2020 and write it to the csv document again.
your help will be very appreciated.

the csv file content is:

```
Score,35,23,12,65,34,111,54,23,68,97
Age,35,23,14,76
Postcode,35065,67443,23545,12323,72335
```

Comment: That's a very unusual csv file.  Why doesn't it have the same number of fields on each line?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for coming back. This is a part of my quiz and the data is provided as I shared. It is asked me to rename the first element of the csv file. It could be a whether score, or age or postcode.. It depends which one is chosen.

Answer (score -1):

csv files are typically structured like this. The top/header line indicates the "column" names and then each subsequent line should contain the values.

Score,Age,Postcode

35,35,35065

23,23,67443

and so on....

edited for bad formatting. I am new to stack overflow